# bash sed how to append to beginning of line, that matches variable at beginning of line

Tags: bash, sed

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to append at the beginning of each line if the beginning of the line matches the servername in a variable. Although nice to have but not required is if no site was matched up, to indicate "unknown-site" at the beginning of line.

I do have a known list of machine names for each site.

```
site1="server1 server2 ..."
site2="server3 ..."
```

I was thinking the code should be something like

```
for each servername in $site1 do; sed command in file
for each servername in $site2 do; sed command in file
```

The raw data that was supplied to me

```
server1 data1...
server1 data2...
server3 data3...
server3 data2...
server2 data4...
server3 data3...
server2 data5...
```

And this should be the out put

```
site1 server1 data1...
site1 server1 data2...
site2 server3 data3...
site2 server3 data2...
site1 server2 data4...
site2 server3 data3...
site1 server2 data5...
```

Comment: Where do you get the machine names for each site from?

Comment: the machine names is a manually created list. It is "known" to be accurate.

Comment: Could they be put in a file?

Comment: sure... just a copy/paste away...

Comment: side note, I'm a "Windows guy" trying to do it the "Linux way"

Answer (score 0):

If you can arrange the server<>site mapping to one file (`servers`) like this:

```
server1 site1
server2 site1
server3 site2
```

Then this becomes easy to do with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {s[$1] = $2; next} {print s[$1], $0}' servers in
site1 server1 data1...
site1 server1 data2...
site2 server3 data3...
...
```

`NR` is the number of records (lines) seen by `awk` this far, `FNR` the number of records within this file seen this far. Comparing them with `FNR==NR` is a common idiom for separating the first file from the rest. So, for each line of the first file, we set the values found to the array `s`, with the first field (`$1`) as key, and the second (`$2`) as value, then jump to `next` line. (All arrays in `awk` are associative, and work with strings as keys/indexes.) Now we have the site names matching the servers in array `s` (e.g. `s["server1"] == "site1"`) and for the subsequent files, we just use the first field as an index to the array, print the value found there, along with the full input line (`$0`).

We could also add a known marker (instead of empty) for the unknown ones by checking if `s[$1]` exists and is nonempty:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {s[$1] = $2; next} {if (s[$1]) print s[$1], $0; else print "unknown", $0;  next}' servers data.txt
```

With the server names as you had in the shell, you could produce the `servers` file with something like this:

```
site1="server1 server2 ..."
site2="server3 ..."
true > servers        # to clear the file
for x in $site1 ; do echo "$x site1" ; done >> servers
for x in $site2 ; do echo "$x site2" ; done >> servers
```

Comment: creating the server<>site file would be very labour intensive for a few hundred servers...

Comment: I've never used awk before... can you explain what you're doing?  and how do I specify the "datafile" and the "servesitepairing" file? I need to understand...

Comment: hmmm... and to create the pair file I can simply do something like(gotta double check the syntax later but)... $for servername in site1 do; echo -e "$servername SiteName\n" >> serversitepairfile

Comment: @cwheeler33, yeah, something like that. Edited to add that and an explanation on the awk..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -F '[ ="]+' 'NR==FNR {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { sites[$i]=$1; }; next }
                 { print sites[$1] " " $0 }' sites data
```